# Como pegar parte de uma String?

Tags: java

Preciso pegar somente o  `[nItem:2]` da Frase:

```
Nota fiscal - 502: Status do retorno da transmissão: 778 - Informado NCM inexistente [nItem:2]
```

Alguem teria alguma ideia?

Lembrando que só interessa o trecho [nItem:XXX]

Comment: Este dado é constante? Ou ele pode er outros valores alem de 2?

Comment: Pode conter outros valores

Comment: Há alguma parte desse trecho que não mude?

Comment: O melhor é mesmo dar mais exemplos de situações onde vai buscar os valores, para se conseguir perceber melhor qual é o padrão. Muito frequentemente a pessoa dá apenas um exemplo particular, quando noutras situações já precisa de agir de forma diferente

Comment: O texto é estático o que pode mudar é o numero da nota fiscal, no caso 502, o retorno da transmissão, no caso 778 e o nItem, no caso 2, que pode ter mais de 1 caractere.

Comment: @LeandroSantos pra você só interessa o trecho `[nItem:XXX]` correto?

Comment: Isso correto...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Já temos algumas respostas que atendem o cenário, porém, gostaria de compartilhar minha solução utilizando expressões regulares.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class q317584 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String linha = "Nota fiscal - 502: Status do retorno da transmissão: 778 - Informado NCM inexistente [nItem:2]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[nItem:(\\d*)]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(linha);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Uma das vantagens dessa abordagem é a assertividade.

Independente do que vier antes, depois, espaços a mais, espaços a menos, o pattern sempre vai pegar o próximo número depois da tag `[nItem:`

Acredito também que deixa o código mais limpo e inteligível, sem utilizar `.split`, `.substring`, que dependendem de [números mágicos](https://www.devmedia.com.br/numeros-magicos-o-que-sao-e-como-corrigir/38711) para tornar a solução viável.

Answer (score 2):

Levando em conta sua necessidade a partir dos esclarecimentos nos comentários da questão, isto deve bastar:

```
String linha = "Nota fiscal - 502: Status do retorno da transmissão: 778 - Informado NCM inexistente [nItem:2]";
System.out.println(linha.substring(linha.lastIndexOf(":")+1, linha.length()-1)); //imprimirá 2
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, porem se o nItem for 10, ele pegara somente o 0 correto ? Ai terei problemas

Comment: Cara não tinha testado, resolveu meu problema, desculpe a ignorância rs muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Quebre a string com `.split(" ")` usando o espaço como separador, e então pegue o último item da lista :P

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela resposta, tentei assim mais obtive um erro.
 String teste[] = o.split("[");
                           System.out.println("ITEM "+teste[0]); //imprime o item
                           String erroTratado = teste[0];
                           erroTratado = erroTratado.replace("[nItem", "");
                           erroTratado = erroTratado.replace("]", "");
                            System.out.println("NUMERO DO ITEM: "+erroTratado);